# external monitor from imac: minidisplayport:hdmi, hdmi:displayport, not recognizing connected monitor

Tags: display, macos, hdmi, displayport

I just got a new samsung monitor: S24E650DW and want to connect it to my imac. I had an mini-display to HDMI, and the store didn't have an mini-display to display port, so I thought I could use the hdmi-displayport.

The late 2015 imac running 10.12.6 however doesn't recognize that a external monitor i connected. In settings "displays" only show the build in retina display, and of course the samsung display show only a black screen, showing that it is set for display-port.

I have two mini-display to HDMI and tried both, so I think they should be working. Of course I tried both in both ports on the imac. The HDMI-display port-cable is brand new, and I don't have any way to test it, but I guess I must assume it works. I have tested the display on another computer at work, and it works fine.

I can't figure out what it is. that I don't understand. I read somewhere online that mini-display to display-port should work, I don't know if it is the HDMI junction that mess it up. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Those combination of cable and adapters generally work well, so you have good chances of success assuming the display isn’t an odd implementation of the signaling standards or something is actually broken in the total assembly.

Comment: Thank you. That's very usefull. I thought that I should be able to check the display connecting it to my apple TV using HDMI-Displayport:display. 
It doesn't work, so assuming that you should be able to see the apple TV on this connection(??), either the cable is defect or I broke the display transporting it home..

Comment: No - iMac to Apple TV won’t work even with all good connections and hardware. Neither will accept as input the others output. Whoever sold or supports the Samsung monitor needs to support you in determining if it’s fit and configured properly.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. What i meant was appleTV-samsung monitor. 
I tried getting a new HDMI:displayport cable, but it's the same. I guess that I maybe broke the display, without knowing it then. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Aah. That would be a solid test. Proving the cables and iMac are fine to the extent they are common. You’re probably as good at troubleshooting this than I would be if not better.